# How can I view invalid characters in a file?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, text-editor

How can I view invalid characters in a (text) file?

At the left is Notepad++ on a Windows machine. At the right is TextWrangler on a Mac machine. Notepad++ shows me what those invalid characters are, but TextWrangler just displays inverted question marks. How can I view those invalid characters (more meaningfully) on Mac?

[image]

OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
Hardware: MacBook Pro Mid-2015

Comment: What makes a character invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) can display the invalid characters.

[image]